# Update db entry depending form data

Tags: php, forms, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have a simple registration form which has 3 fields. Email, name and password. So far so good. I'm able to create new users. The problem comes when I want to edit user information.

I want to update password field in the database only if html password field is not empty

```
public function editAction(User $user, Request $request)
    {
        $form = $this->createForm(new UserForm(), $user);

        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()){
            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $em->persist($user);
            $em->flush();
            $this->redirectToRoute('bd_user_list');
        }

        return $this->render('BDUserBundle:User:add.html.twig', [
            'form' => $form->createView()
        ]);
    }
```

If I left password field blank I get this error (which is normal)

```
An exception occurred while executing 'UPDATE users SET password = ? WHERE id = ?' with params [null, 5]:

SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'password' cannot be null
```

I've read about validation groups but I'm not sure they can help.

// the solution

UserForm.php

```
[...]
builder->addEventSubscriber(new UserFormListener());
[...]
```

UserFormListener.php

```
<?php

namespace SDUserBundle\Form\EventListener;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormEvent;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormEvents;
use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface;

class UserFormListener implements EventSubscriberInterface
{
    private $password;

    public static function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        return array(
            FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA => 'preSetData',
            FormEvents::POST_SUBMIT => 'postSubmit'
        );
    }

    public function preSetData(FormEvent $event)
    {
        $this->password = $event->getData()->getPassword();
    }

    public function postSubmit(FormEvent $event)
    {
        $data = $event->getData();

        if ($data->getPassword() == false) {
            $data->setPassword($this->password);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Fast solution

Modify your code as follows

```
public function editAction(User $user, Request $request)
{
    $old_pwd = $user->getPassword(); //or whatever the method is called

    $form = $this->createForm(new UserForm(), $user);
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()){
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        if (null == $user->getPassword()) {
            $user->setPassword($old_pwd);
        }
        $em->persist($user);
        $em->flush();
        $this->redirectToRoute('bd_user_list');
    }

    return $this->render('BDUserBundle:User:add.html.twig', [
        'form' => $form->createView()
    ]);
}
```

### More elegant solution

This is a first solution but involves some logic inside controller; maybe you need that code elsewhere, so you could migrate it into form events like [`FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA`](http://symfony.com/it/doc/current/components/form/form_events.html#a-l-evento-formevents-pre-set-data)

So you need to modify your `UserForm` as follows

```
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormEvent;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormEvents;
[...]

class UserForm extends AbstractType
{
    private $old_pwd;

    [...]
    $builder
        [...] 
        ->addEventListener(FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA, function(FormEvent $event) {
            $data = $event->getData();
            $this->old_pwd = $data->getPassword();
        })
        ->addEventListener(FormEvents::POST_SUBMIT, function(FormEvent $event) {
            $data = $event->getData();
            if (false == $data->getPassword()) {
                $data->setPassword($this->old_pwd);
                $this->setData($data);
            }
        })
}
```

I really don't know if second approach is a working one as I can't test it at the moment but `FormEvents` should help you accomplish what you need.

### Another approach, not so good?

Maybe you could modify User setter directly

```
class User
{
    [...]
    public function setPassword($pwd)
    {
        if ($pwd) {
            $this->pwd = //logic here to store a safe pwd
        }
    }
}
```

Why this third solution is the worst at all I let you to find yourself ;)

#### Side note

Just to let you know that `isValid()` take care for you about submitted controls from Symfony2.3 on so you don't need `isSubmitted()` control explicitly

Comment: Thanks. I updated my question with the solution based on your recommendations. Have a look & let me know how do you find it

Comment: @Vodokan: yes, you could proceed even that way. So it works? Why did you use preSetData instead of preSubmit? is preSubmit too late?

Comment: not sure if PRE_SUBMIT is too late but I get not existing method getPassword error in this code 
` $this->password = $event->getData()->getPassword()` on PRE_SUBMIT event.